# Is there a Stack Exchange site for shopping, e.g., men's wear?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for shopping, e.g., men's wear?

I am looking for a good online shop for a turtle neck, American size.

Comment: ZOMBIE STEVE JOBS! RUN!

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there's a Stack Exchange site for that. Most SE sites frown on recommendation questions, since they attract spam. Most of the sites are for professionals and enthusiasts looking to learn about a subject, so it's possible that someone might propose a site (on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)) about fashion or men's wear, but it's unlikely that they'd start a site where recommendations on where to shop would be on-topic.

Comment: Even "fashion" would not make a good subject for an SE site, it changes way too fast.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Unlike JavaScript? ;)

Answer (score 9):

No, and it's pretty unlikely. While there's been a few experiments, with product recommendations sites, it's not really something that fits the Q&A model very well.

Website recommendations (specific as in your case or general) aren't something that's happened yet and what a "good online shop" is is kinda ultra subjective and not a great subject for a question.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that, in addition to being completely subjective most of the time, such questions rarely stand the test of time - what is the "best" place to get something or the "best" product in a certain category (whether in tech or fashion) is likely to change drastically over time, and previous recommendations may quickly become out of date.